# How to make existing flash site work in iPhone and iPads?

Tags: iphone, flash, video-streaming, html5-video, video-encoding

My current HTML4 transitional website has several flash videos. How could I make them play in Apple devices with minimal changes?

I've seen numerous threads but I've got confused. Some possible ways suggested in these threads:

1. Identify device from request and serve another format video. Which format should be served here? I need to maintain all videos in 2 format? H.264 encoding was suggested [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8513/if-iphones-ipads-dont-support-flash-how-do-they-play-youtube).
2. [HTML 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595780/what-is-the-best-way-to-serve-videos-on-a-website)  options. Not feasible in my case. Rewriting pages in HTML5 is not an option for me.

Could someone please suggest the recommended way for my case? Thanks.

Comment: Option 2 is the *most feasible* case - why isn't it so for you? It's not that difficult, just change the DOCTYPE, tidy up some elements to meet HTML5 standards and implement some [nifty JavaScript libraries](http://html5video.org/) to play your videos. Also, is uploading your videos to a service like Viemo or YouTube and embedding them not an option? That would probably be the fastest/easiest.

Comment: @iND iPhone and iPads don't, and never will, support Flash. If support for them is a requirement "keep the existing Flash solution" simply won't work.

Comment: Sorry, was looking for a tut, and posted my flippant comment accidentally.  Anyway, for Flash/Air options, look at this tut:  http://sonnati.wordpress.com/2011/04/26/air-2-6-for-ios-and-video-playback/  Flash -- Flash IDE, FlashDevelop, FlashBuilder -- can produce Air products, which can be made into iOS apps.  The problem comes with what video format is required.

Comment: Can an iOS apps be embedded onto a web page though? (Not sure how that all works).

Comment: Hm . . . that's what I get for watching [Peep Show](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peep_Show_%28TV_series%29) while trying to think.  Not apps, websites . . . ok, look into HTML5, probably.

Comment: Yep, gonna delete my comments soon.  :-|

Comment: @iND Haha, 'tis how we learn :) Besides, your comments are likely going to be useful for eliminating the OP's ability to try side-step using HTML5 and then getting stuck again anyway.

Comment: @MartyWallace I do learn a lot watching Peep Show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> HTML 5 options. Not feasible in my case. Rewriting pages in HTML5 is not an option for me.

I think you're a little misinformed about what supporting HTML5 entails.

Replace `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">` with `<!doctype html>`. Done! You can use the new tags in HTML5, but you don't have to. Things are nicely [backwards compatible](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#backwards-compatible) with just a few (rare) edge cases.

Encode everything as H.264 and you'll have the easiest time. Serve the files with Flash for desktop if you like, and serve via the HTML5 `<video>` tag to mobile devices.

Consider using a nice hybrid HTML5/Flash pre-built player like [Video.js](http://videojs.com/) or [SublimeVideo](http://sublimevideo.net/) to make your life easier.

Comment: awesome. I wasn't aware of HTML5 backward compatibility.