# Play video on browser without installing player in remote computer

Tags: html

How to play video file in webrowser without installing any player software in the remote computer? I think this is on fly video playing concept and lots of sites using this 
I'm using VLC media player to play video on the browser. Is there any way so that I can play video on the remote browser without installing any software.

Maybe I can tell them to install plugins for that?

Answer (score 1):

> there is any way so i can play video on the remote browser without installing any software

Nope, there isn't. You will always need video playing capability on the client side. (Well, short of turning the videos into Animated GIFs, but that is madness.)

The best supported Video embedding methods are Flash Video and HTML 5 Video. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086886/html-5-video-tag-vs-flash-video-what-are-the-pros-and-cons) for detailed information on the two.

Answer (score 0):

use this code in any control to play video

```
<video controls="controls" id="id1" width="200" height="200">
<source  src="movie/show.mp4" />
</video>
```